# How can I pass $id from view to controller in codeigniter.?

Tags: codeigniter-3

```
    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/Book/delete .$book->book_id;" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
```

Book/delete is functions in controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('Book/delete').'/'.$book->book_id; class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
```

Then change your delete method as public and send ID param there like:

```
public function delete($book_id){
    echo $book_id;
}
```